# Access SourceBranchName in Release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to release my buildartifacts to a specific folder based on the name of the sourcebranch which upon creating a pull request triggered the build and therefor the release.

I've managed to so far to get:

```
write-host $env:RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS
$triggerAlias = $env:RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS
```

This alias (from my point of view) is the primary artifcat alias which I need to access

```
Release.Artifacts.{Primary artifact alias}.SourceBranchName
```

based on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#artifact-variables). So how do I combine the alias to get the sourcebranchname

```
$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_{$triggerAlias}_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
```

This doesn't seem to be working and neither does

```
$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_$($triggerAlias)_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the variable in this way:

```
$triggerAlias = $env:RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS

$branchNameVariable = "RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_$($triggerAlias)_SOURCEBRANCHNAME"

#Get the value of the environment variable Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceBranchName
$branchName = (Get-item env:$branchNameVariable).Value
```

Comment: Given the speed of your reply it looks like it's the most obvious answer in the world ;-) but I did not find any example like this before. Thank you very much, it worked

Comment: I'll tell you the truth, last week I ran into the same problem and after searching I solved it this way :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'll try to get Microsoft to include this kind of example to their documentation aswell. Let's see if that works out